# Get rows from this year with a datetime field

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

First sorry if the question has already been asked but I couldn't find a correct answer to my question.

Soo I have a table with a row called "date_commande" and the type is "datetime()".

I just want all rows where the "date_commande" are from this current year.

So I tried with this code :

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM produit 
    WHERE date_commande = YEAR(CURDATE())                         
    ORDER BY num_serie_produit desc;
```

This returns me nothing ...

Thx

Comment: You probably haven't searched for long as this is quite trivial using the `YEAR` function you know about. And your comparison is obviously wrong (why use "smaller than" when you need an "equal to" ?)

Comment: I edited but the problem doesn't come from that ...

Comment: what do you get if you execute SELECT top 1 * FROM my_table

Comment: try YEAR(date_commande) = YEAR(CURDATE())

Comment: What do you mean when you say : top 1 *

Comment: TOP 1 is for SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Oh why -2 ? When I see all the wrong answers you proposed me :/ Anw thx for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick :

```
SELECT * 
FROM produit 
WHERE YEAR(date_commande) = YEAR(CURDATE())                         
ORDER BY num_serie_produit desc;
```

Comment: parentheses after curdate().

Answer (score 1):

try `YEAR(date_commande) = YEAR(CURDATE())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE year(date_commande) = YEAR(CURDATE())                         
ORDER BY num_serie_produit desc;
```

Comment: and this is different where?.. a the equal sign

Comment: you have used '<' cond while i have used '=' cond.

Comment: same nothing changed :/

Comment: For current year you have to use '=' sign rahter than <'

Comment: well this answer is obviously wrong as you want to extract YEAR part of `date_commande` before doing the comparison...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM produit WHERE date_commande = YEAR(getdate())
```

Comment: getdate() doesn't support in MYSQL.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai he didn't specify if its Mysql or MS SQL...and he tagged both MySQl and SQL. Whats the downvote for?

Comment: He clearly specify MYSQL. Still you are using GETDATE().

Comment: This is his title "Get rows from this year with a datetime field" and tags include MySQL and SQL. Are we maybe not reading the same title or something.

Comment: try to understand. SQL is just the community under which all DBMSs comes such as MYSQL, ORACLE, SYBASE etc. SQL iss quite different with MSSQL.